# How to change the camera position with mouse dragging in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I've made a Rolex cube kind of geometry with difference in "Z axis" between each layer. Now I want to change the camera position so that I could check the geometry is exactly what I was expecting. My question is how to change the camera position while dragging the window and also should be able manipulate the rotation of each individual cone based on mouse event.

Here is my jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sagh0900/gfraQ/8/

sample code but please make sure you visit jsfiddle to get detail idea of my question:

```
for ( var i = 0; i <nSize; i++)
{
    var k = i%10,
        j = (i-k)/10;

    j = j*2 - 10;
    k = k*2 - 10;

    var cone1 = lc_relationship.sensor1[i].Geometry; 
    scene.add(cone1);
    var cone2 = lc_relationship.sensor2[i].Geometry;
    scene.add(cone2);
    var cone3 = lc_relationship.sensor3[i].Geometry;
    scene.add(cone3);
    cone1.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor1[i].z_cordinate);
    cone2.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor2[i].z_cordinate);
    cone3.position.set(j, k, lc_relationship.sensor3[i].z_cordinate);
}
```

If someone could update my jsfiddle or provide me help is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a empty (null) mesh to add objects instead scene: Mesh

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.Geometry());
scene.add(mesh);
/*[...]*/
mesh.add(cone1);
/*[...]*/
mesh.add(cone2);
/*[...]*/
mesh.add(cone3);
/*[...]*/
```

And add this to rotate this mesh:

```
var screenW = window.innerWidth;
var screenH = window.innerHeight; /*SCREEN*/
var spdx = 0, spdy = 0; mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, mouseDown = false; /*MOUSE*/
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    mouseDown = true
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    mouseDown = false
}, false);
function animate() {    
    spdy =  (screenH / 2 - mouseY) / 40;
    spdx =  (screenW / 2 - mouseX) / 40;
    if (mouseDown){
        mesh.rotation.x = spdy;
        mesh.rotation.y = spdx;
    }
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/gfraQ/11/

Comment: That is so wonderful reply of you and I'm so glad to comment you back. could you also sort me out, how to select and rotate individual cone on layer and its child  or parent on immediate layer simultaneously based on their ID's in the JSON (here it is java object). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tnxs!, put them on array, ej: / var miCones = []; mesh.add(cone1); miCones.push(cone1); mesh.add(cone2); miCones2.push(cone2); [...]

Comment: This is exactly what my intention was, I want to select individual cone and it following children as single selection. for ex: If I select the cone1 on layer 1 and rotate, its child in layer2 and its grand children in layer 3 should be selected and got to rotate at a time. And if I select cone on layer 2, if it has parent on layer 1 it also be selected and its child in layer 3 should be selected for rotation. Like wise a cone on layer 3 has to come up with its parents on previous layers for rotation. These selections depend on JSON [javascript object here]. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Maybe: mesh.add(cone1); cone1.add(cone2); cone2.add(cone3) ?

Comment: I didn't get you dude, are you asking me or suggesting me? If you have gone through the Javascript object, you could get an idea how is the relationship between the cones. I tried my best but am out of luck :(